# Why I can't add in database?

Tags: php, html, json, ajax, mysqli

I am trying to send data from html to php,where I try to add it in my database.
I just can't figure out what is wrong,can anyone help me please?

Here is the code in the script:

```
 $("#addbtn").click(function(){
    var cityName=document.getElementById("cityField").value.toString();
    var countryName=document.getElementById("countryField").value;
    var description=document.getElementById("descriptionField").value;
    var touristTargets=document.getElementById("targetsField").value;
    var costPerDay=parseInt(document.getElementById("costField").value);
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      url: "getCities.php",
      data: {limit:100,action:"add",cityField:cityField,countryField:countryField,descriptionField:descriptionField,targetsField:targetsField,costField:costPerDay},
      success: {function(msg) {
        alert(msg.status);
      }}

    });
```

And this one in php file:

```
  $action= $_REQUEST["action"];
  if($action == "add"){
    $city=json_decode($_GET["cityField"]);
    $country=json_decode($_GET["countryField"]);
    $descript=json_decode($_GET["descriptionField"]);
    $targets=json_decode($_GET["targetsField"]);
    $cost=json_decode($_GET["costField"]);
    $command="INSERT INTO vacantiondestinations(cityName,countryName,description,touristTargets,costPerDay) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare($command);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssi",$city,$country,$descript,$targets,$cost);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt)
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success'));
    else
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'failed'));

    }
```

Comment: `if($_GET['action'] == "add"){` in place of `if($action == "add"){`

Comment: I have defined :  $action= $_REQUEST["action"]; but I forgot to add it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used wrong variables name , the code should be like:

data:{limit:100,action:"add",cityField:cityName,countryField:countryName,descriptionField:description,targetsField:touristTargets,costField:costPerDay},

Answer (score 1):

Since you are declaring these variables - shouldn't they be the values included in your data declaration (code truncated to show just the important stuff?

```
    var cityName=...
    var countryName=...
    var description=...
    var touristTargets=...
    var costPerDay=...

...data: {limit:100,action:"add",cityField:cityName,countryField:countryName,descriptionField:description,targetsField:touristTargets,costField:costPerDay}...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't appear to be encoding the data as JSON anywhere, most of the time when you call `json_decode($_GET["somevalue"])` you are going to get NULL.

Don't run `json_decode` over things that are not JSON.